# Changing Kafka In-sync replicas

Tags: apache-kafka, replication, partition

We are running open source Kafka Confluent 5.2.1 using Avro to encode/decode messages. When we build out a new cluster and publish the schemas to it, our `__consumer_offsets` topic has the following configurations:

```
$shell> kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181/apps/kafka_cluster --describe --topic __consumer_offsets
Topic:__consumer_offsets        PartitionCount:50       ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 101     Replicas: 101   Isr: 101
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 102     Replicas: 102   Isr: 102
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 101     Replicas: 101   Isr: 101
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 102     Replicas: 102   Isr: 102
...
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 48   Leader: 101     Replicas: 101   Isr: 101
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 49   Leader: 102     Replicas: 102   Isr: 102
```

I then reassign the partitions using the following JSON file:

```
{"version":1, "partitions":[
  {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":0,"replicas":[101,102,103]},
  {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":1,"replicas":[102,103,101]},
  {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":2,"replicas":[103,101,102]},
...
  {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":45,"replicas":[101,102,103]},
  {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":46,"replicas":[102,103,101]},
  {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":47,"replicas":[103,101,102]},
  {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":48,"replicas":[101,102,103]},
  {"topic":"__consumer_offsets","partition":49,"replicas":[102,103,101]}
]}
```

The end result has replicas changes, but in-sync replicas are sometimes changing and sometimes not:

```
$shell> kafka-topics --zookeeper bigdevmq02c:2181/apps/kafka_cluster --describe --topic __consumer_offsets                Topic:__consumer_offsets        PartitionCount:50       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 101     Replicas: 101,102,103   Isr: 101
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 102     Replicas: 102,103,101   Isr: 102,103,101
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 101     Replicas: 103,101,102   Isr: 101
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 102     Replicas: 101,102,103   Isr: 102,103,101
...
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 48   Leader: 101     Replicas: 101,102,103   Isr: 101
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 49   Leader: 102     Replicas: 102,103,101   Isr: 102,103,101
```

I would like to have the in-sync replicas match the replicas, and then run the leader election based on the first member of the replicas, something like this:

`$shell> kafka-preferred-replica-election --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

but that currently fails. What have I done wrong and how do I correct it?

Thank you very much for your help.

**UPDATE**

I ran a verify, and on an empty cluster after 2.5 hours it is still showing incomplete:

```
$shell> kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper localhost:2181/apps/kafka_cluster --reassignment-json-file dev.json --verify
Status of partition reassignment:
Reassignment of partition __consumer_offsets-22 is still in progress
Reassignment of partition __consumer_offsets-30 is still in progress
Reassignment of partition __consumer_offsets-8 is still in progress
Reassignment of partition __consumer_offsets-21 completed successfully
```

Comment: Did the reassign --verify command show it was complete?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the suggestion, I did not know there was an option like that. Please see the update -- it is showing still in progress, but the cluster only has one topic with subjects, why would it take more than a couple of hours?

Comment: On an empty cluster, I'm not sure. Are there any errors in the broker logs to indicate replication isn't working?

Comment: @cricket_007 Just a mistake, the misbehaving node turned out the be running the older version of Kafka. I am not sure why it is not really backward compatible, but lesson learned. Thank you so much for trying to help.

Comment: Probably because the message format changed between versions. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a while, we noticed that there is one node in the cluster which is running Kafka version 5.2.1, and the rest were running 5.3.1. Changing the version running on that node to 5.3.1 fixed the problem.